# Dropdown list in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to create a dropdown list and I get nothing in the dropdown except 'Please select one' but no values.

I've tried this so far:

View:

```
<select asp-for="StatusToEdit.Color.Name" asp-items="Model.AvailableColors">
     <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
   public SelectList AvailableColors { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        AvailableColors = new SelectList(nameof(StatusColor.ColorId), 
        nameof(StatusColor.Name));
    }
```

Mocklist:

```
    private static List<ItemStatus> _mockStatuses = new List<ItemStatus>
    {
        new ItemStatus  { StatusId = 1, Name = "Complete", Color = new 
         StatusColor{ ColorId = 1, Name = "Auto" } },
        new ItemStatus  { StatusId = 2, Name = "Complete, Ongoing", Color =  
        new StatusColor{ ColorId = 2, Name = "Green" }},
        new ItemStatus  { StatusId = 3, Name = "In Process", Color = new 
        StatusColor{ ColorId = 3, Name = "Yellow" }}
    };
```

I expect to see all of the colors to show in the dropdown.

Comment: Make sure you're defining your list correctly. See this: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/forms/select-lists `You can create a SelectList from any collection but you need to specify the DataTextField and DataValueField values for the select tag helper to bind the options correctly`. See the page for more details.

Comment: I've tried that. Still can't get anything to show. I updated my original post with more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your list as below:

```
ViewBag.ColorList = new SelectList(_mockStatuses.Select(d=> { return new SelectListItem { Text = d.Color.Name, Value = d.Color.ColorId.ToString() }; }),"Value","Text");
```

I used ViewBag for it but you can obviously pass it to your view by a ViewModel if you prefer.

For your View you should do something as below:

```
<select asp-items="@ViewBag.ColorList" asp-for="StatusToEdit.Color.Name" >
    <option value="">Please select one</option>
</select>
```

Please make sure you have added Value and Text at the end of SelectList when creating it.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using asp.net core MVC (Razor Pages is similar), you need to modify the model property type to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem> AvailableColors` or `List<SelectListItem> AvailableColors`

1.Model

```
public class ManageStatusesEditViewModel
{
    //other properties
    public List<SelectListItem> AvailableColors { get; set; }
}
```

2.Action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ManageStatusesEdit(int id)
    {
        //other logic
        var dropdownData = new List<SelectListItem>();

        _mockStatuses.ForEach(d => dropdownData.Add(new SelectListItem()
        {
            Value = d.Color.Name,
            Text = d.Color.Name
        }));

        var editManageStatusesEditViewModel = new ManageStatusesEditViewModel
        {

            AvailableColors = dropdownData
        };
        return View(editManageStatusesEditViewModel);
    }
```

3.View:

```
<select asp-for="StatusToEdit.Color.Name" asp-items="Model.AvailableColors">
    <option>Please select one</option>
</select>
```

4.Result:

[image]